# Error when trying to return promise from mongoose save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I am using `mongoose` and `express` within `node`.

I am running into a problem with a nested promise and can't figure out why this is happening.

**Route** - /loans

```
router.post('/problems/add', (req, res, next) => {
// error checking
  req.headers.api = 'true';

  let required = ['loan', 'item', 'type', 'quantity', 'description'];
  let problems = [];

  required.forEach(r => {
    if (!req.body[r]){
      problems.push(`Field '${r}' was not supplied`);
    }
  });

  if (problems.length > 0){
    res.json({success: false, message: `Couldn't create problem:\n${problems.join('\n')}`});
  } else {

// Important part
    loanController.addProblem(req.body)
    .then((newProblem) => { // line 118 mentioned in error message
      res.json({success: true, problem: newProblem});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return next(err);
    })
  }

});
```

**Controller** - loanController

```
exports.addProblem = (body) => {

  Loan.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.loan)).exec()
  .then(foundLoan => {

    if (!foundLoan){
      throw new Error('loan not found');
    }

    let newProblem = new Problem({
      loan: foundLoan._id,
      item: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.item),
      type: body.type,
      quantity: body.quantity,
      status: 'new',
      text: body.description
    });

    return newProblem.save(); // newProblem is a valid mongoose document
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });

}
```

I'm getting the error below, it's not getting caught by any of these catch blocks and is coming from my general error trapping:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined    at router.post (c:\dev....\loans.js:118:5)

Now when I put a breakpoint at `newProblem.save()`, it shows `newProblem` being a valid Mongoose document, these documents are being saved correctly.
I'm even able to call `newProblem.save().then()` from the debug command line.

I assume I've made an error somewhere but this is structured similarly to other objects and they work fine.

Can anyone spot the error I've made or suggest a way to investigate further?

Comment: `addProblem` does not return anything.

Comment: @str it returns `newProblem.save()` or am I mistaken? If I breakpoint on that return line it's being hit.

Comment: The return statement is within a callback, but that does not do anything outside of the callback. You need to do `return Loan.findById(/*...*/).exec()`.

Comment: @str But I don't want to return the promise from the `findById`, I just want to use this object in the function to create the new document.

Comment: That does not return the promise from `findById`. I suggest you read up on promise chaining.